# WP-admin is not working, showing php errors

Tags: php, wordpress

```
Warning: require(wp-blog-header.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/tratam79/public_html/masoarafebra.ro/wp-admin/index.php on line 17

Warning: require(wp-blog-header.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/tratam79/public_html/masoarafebra.ro/wp-admin/index.php on line 17

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/tratam79/public_html/masoarafebra.ro/wp-admin/index.php on line 17
```

Those are the errors I get when trying to access wp-admin. As of now I've tried forging the full URL to the files. Any ideas?

Comment: wp-blog-header.php file not found. Did you install anything recently?

Comment: disable all plugins and activate the default WP theme and see what happens.

Comment: I would but I don't have access to the admin. I'm not sure about installing anything recently because they are clients to the company I work at and someone else did the project and never have logged in..

Answer (score 0):

It could be your wordpress file is missing or not accessible. If you just upload it, it might be it is not uploaded completely.

Comment: Hmn, well, it had an older version of WP, so I also did the upgrade to 3.5.1, but manually.

Comment: A colleague of mine discovered what was happening. A while back I used a cron job to help avoid a recurring virus. Problem was said cron was looking for ALL the index.php files on that domain and replacing them with a single file. As such it also replaced wp-admin's index.php.. Yes, it was very stupid of me.